# Configure gstreamer to use openGLES instead of openGL

Tags: opengl-es, gstreamer, mali

My target uses the rockchip Mali GPU, which supports OpenGLES, but not OpenGL. My target is built from buildroot & my application requires simple GPU transformations, for which the gl plugin (from gstreamer-plugins-bad) would be incredibly helpful. Unfortunately, this gl plugin requires opengl, which I mentioned before is not supported by Mali.

Is there any way to configure gl to use OpenGLES? Or is there a template/github that I can bring into my project in order to get GPU transformations in my gstreamer pipeline?

I have tried the opengl plugin, but without GPU support the software implementation is very slow & processor intensive.

Ultimately I would love to have a plugin with a simple implementation as follows:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! myplugin x-rot=52 ! autovideosink
```

Comment: i was able to fix this. I needed to do a clean build. and go through and enable the correct compositor for your target. In my instance it was the wayland compositor. Its not very easy to find, but gstreamer will get built after the windowing system is configured.